# Problem with registering webhook url on twitter app

Tags: php, webhooks, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to register a webhook url on twitter app and I'm using this package [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth).

Here's what I've code.

```
$cbUrl = 'https://123456.ngrok.io';
$envName = 'myDevEnvironment';
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
$data = $connection->post('account_activity/all/' . $envName . '/webhooks', ['url' => urlencode($cbUrl)]);
```

I'm using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to get https of my localhost webhook url. But still getting error code 214 in response and below error message.

```
{"errors":[{"code":214,"message":"Webhook URL does not meet the requirements. Please use HTTPS."}]}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: My guess - their check for whether the supplied URL starts with `https://` probably fails, because you URL-encoded the value. Your package likely takes care of encoding any parameter values in API calls itself, so in this case, you would have encoded it _twice_ now. And no matter how long anyone stares as `https%3A%2F%2F123456.ngrok.io`, that does not start with `https://`

Comment: You are right, url gets encoded twice, that's why It can't identify whether it is secured or not. Thank you @CBroe for quick help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ['url' => urlencode($cbUrl)]
> ```

Their check for whether the supplied URL starts with `https://` probably fails, because you URL-encoded the value. Your package likely takes care of encoding any parameter values in API calls itself, so in this case, you would have encoded it twice now.

If they look for `https://` at the start of `https%3A%2F%2F123456.ngrok.io`, that will fail.

Answer (score -2):

`Please use HTTPS.`.

The error is self explanitory, your requests are being denied because you are not on an secure connetcion. Install an SSL certificate on your server.

Here's the ngrok docs on Transport Layer Security

https://ngrok.com/docs#tls

Comment: No, this is not self-explanatory in this situation here. ngrok provides an SSL _tunnel_, that is what they do. The ngrok URL they tried to specify here, _does_ use HTTPS. And that is all that should be needed. The server behind this, that ngrok is tunneling _to_, does not need to support HTTPS - it is invisible to the outside anyway.